# If thing exists, do something with thing

Tags: python

What is the correct (pythonic) way to do something like this?

```
var = 'The quick brown fox'

def exists(query, string):
    if query in string:
        return query
    else:
        return None

if thing = exists('fox', var):
    print(thing.upper())
```

This is my example, but what I'm really trying to do is check if a Selenium web element exists. I want to avoid setting the result to a variable because that defeats the purpose of "exists". Also, I don't want to perform the search twice returning true/false the first time and then again, if it's true, to do something with it.

Comment: how can you use thing if you never define it? Also how would you be performing the search twice?

Comment: `print(*[item.upper() for item in ['fox'] if item in var][0:])`? ...Yeah, just save the variable as suggested above.

Comment: I regularly do things like `temp = filedialog.askopenfilename()`, `if temp: use_filename(temp)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases where *there's more than one way to do it*.  A few things you could do:

1. Treat the result as a collection of zero to one elements (it makes more sense if you call it something like `find_one` in such cases):

   ```
   def find_one(query, string):
       if query in string:
           return [query]
       return []
   ```

   Then you can use the function in a `for` loop:

   ```
   for existing_element in find_one(query, string):
       # Do something with existing element
       break
   else:
       # Here if we don't have any elements (note the `break` above)
   ```
2. Pass a callback as the first argument:

   ```
   def if_exists(cb, query, string):
       if query in string:
           cb(query)

   def run_on_valid_query(q):
       # Do something with q

   if_exists(run_on_valid_query, query, string)
   ```
3. Bite the bullet and use an intermediate variable:

   ```
   result = extract_from(query, string)
   if result:  # Do work here
   ```

Comment: I will mull this over. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a way the callback could instead be a dot notation function? For example: `result.cb()` where `cb` is a function that can normally be performed on `result`.

Comment: At that point you're just dealing with a regular function, if you're just calling methods on a result if it exists:  `def do_if_exists(query, doc): result = doc.find(query); if result: result.some_method()`  No need for anything more magical than that.